# android out of memory

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Whether system.gc will avoid android's out of memory exception for bitmap?

Comment: No, it won't. A gc is done automatically if memory is low. Btw, this problem has been discussed many times. If you have this problem in a debugger only, it's a known problem with memory leaks through exceptions. If not, then you're leaking bitmaps, or using too large bitmaps.

Comment: i have found that System.gc() brings improvement with rather big bitmaps but you can not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

`System.gc()` is just an request to jvm to execute gc,  you cannot 100% be sure that it will get executed upon `System.gc()` invocation .

See Also :

- [how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s)